# Overcoming or managing dead time in vehicle steering controller

Tags: steering

I found out there is a dead time in my steering controller after several runs. The transfer function for it in the $s$-domain is:

$$
H(s)=\frac{270 \cdot e^{-0.03s}}{0.015 \cdot s + 1}
$$

To overcome this dead time, should I introduce a compensator? My control theory background is weak so I am unaware of a proper way to manage the dead time.

Comment: Use latex style to write equatiions. Transfer function of what? There are comensators like Smith predictor, but I would rather explore where the dead time came from and modify the system.

Comment: Is it dead-time or deadband position from mechanical hysteresis and stiction. ?  Can you verify?  Deadband can be overcome by reducing actuator slack by design.  Also transfer function looks wrong with e^

Comment: Other answers suggest **DITHERING** as a cure for deadband.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 The exponential $e^{-\tau s}$ just means that there is a time delay of $\tau$ seconds before the output reacts to the input.

Comment: If the deadband excursion time delay is τ = 30ms then f-3dB ~0.3 / 30ms ~ 10Hz and a Gain of 270 or GBW~ 3kHz is unity gain instability frequency so a high order phase lead-lag compensation before 1kHz might work better to inject dither. noise by lead compensation ( HPF gain limited)  R1C1//R2C2 ... althoough something tells me GBW ~ 1kHz  So start with specs for Response time to step and ramp inputs then overshoot and small step response, reduced deadband, then solve.

Comment: @KoenTiels that's right. its a first order with delay

Comment: djack. What is your design acceptance criteria?  Only you can decide.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 my answer is vague but ideally, i would like to reduce the delay time to as minimal as possible. not sure if my answer is helpful but appreciate if you could response.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* djack. On stack exchange, it is better to edit your question to add information requested in comments, rather than adding more comments. Comments are for helping to improve questions and answers, and are distracting, so we try to keep them to a minimum. If all of the information needed to answer the question is contained within it, the comments can be tidied up (deleted).